# How to "extend" an existing method of an existing class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, ember.js

I have a class like this

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  say: function(thing) {
    alert(thing);
  }
});
```

I wish to add something to the method `say` , so that the method becomes

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  say: function(thing) {
    alert(thing);
    alert("Thing is said above! ");
  }
});
```

So that

```
var person = App.Person.create();
person.say("Hello");
```

Output is `Hello` `Thing is said above!` .

I have tried to reopen the class and define the method again like

```
App.Person.reopen({
  say: function(thing) {
    alert("Thing is said above! ");
  }
});
```

But then i am left only with `Thing is said above!` . Is there a way to "extend" a method?
or perform anything similar to achieve this?

also explain how to achieve the same to extend a jquery method ? , like i have jquery method binded to an DOM element and i want to extend that to add more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think yes. Either you call the super function into the inherited function :

```
// Super class
function Person() {
     this.text = "Hello";   
}
Person.prototype.say = function () {
     alert(this.text);   
}

// Inherited class
function TalkativePerson() {
    Person.apply(this); // Call to the super constructor 
    this.extendedText = "How are you ?";
}
TalkativePerson.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // Inheritance
TalkativePerson.prototype.constructor = TalkativePerson;
TalkativePerson.prototype.say = function () { // Here you redefine your method
    Person.prototype.say.call(this);//And then you call the super method
    // Add some stuff here like this :
    alert(this.extendedText);
}

var person = new TalkativePerson();
person.say();
```

Or you can (in your example) directly change the value of the text like this :

```
function TalkativePerson2() {
    this.text += ". How are you ?";
}
TalkativePerson2.prototype = new Person();
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GyELD/1/) is a JSFiddle where you can test it.

Comment: It would be better to set prototype part of inheritance with Object.create (shim for old browsers) and re use Parent constructor by calling `Parent.call(this,args);` in Child or `Person.call(this,args);` in TalkativePerson even though there are no parameters used to initialise instance members you may want to re use Person constructor in the future and worth mentioning how. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 Though the OP is using Ember.js (I think) to "help" with Object definition so no way of knowing what happens there without reading the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `this._super();` in the extended version to have it call the original method. You can see an example of that [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tifim/1/)